# Add class to external navigation when slide auto-play happens : anythingSlider

Tags: javascript, jquery, anythingslider

My anythingSlider looks like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://css-tricks.github.com/AnythingSlider/css/theme-metallic.css">

<div id="externalNav">
Goto <a href="#1">One</a> |
     <a href="#2">Two</a> |
     <a href="#3">Three</a> |
     <a href="#4">Four</a>
</div>

<br><br>

<ul id="slider">
    <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placebear.com/300/200" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placedog.com/300/200" alt="" /></li>
</ul>

    $('#slider').anythingSlider({
    // If true, builds a list of anchor links to link to each panel
    buildNavigation: false,
    autoPlay: true
});
```

When autoplay happens and first slide is active I want to add a class to `<a href="#1">One</a>` (and so on for next slides) so that I can show it as selected. Can any one point out what is the correct approach to make this?
[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ycUB6/10264/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [AnythingSlider Wiki](https://github.com/CSS-Tricks/AnythingSlider/wiki) has just the example you wanted:

> Custom, external navigation controls (with updating "cur" class)
>
> ```
> var nav = $('#externalNav a'),
>     updateNav = function(page){
>         nav
>             .removeClass('cur')
>             .eq(page).addClass('cur');
>     }
>
> $('#slider').anythingSlider({
>     // If true, builds a list of anchor links to link to each panel
>     buildNavigation: false,
>     onInitialized: function(e, slider) {
>         updateNav(slider.currentPage-1);
>     },
>     // Callback before slide animates
>     onSlideBegin: function(e, slider) {
>         updateNav(slider.targetPage-1);
>     }
> });
>
> // set up external links
> nav.click(function(){
>     var slide = $(this).attr('href').substring(1);
>     $('#slider').anythingSlider(slide);
>     return false;
> });
> ```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/ycUB6/76/